# <TD> Cell not showing background images

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I have a code for a table and I have three cells in it. I want each cell to have different background images. But the problem is, only the first cell is showing an image! Please help! My code:

I changed the #topbar td width!

Succesful code:

```
#topbar {
        width: 100%;
        color: transparent;
        font-size: 13px;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #topbar td {
        width: 8.33333%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    #topbar td {
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        white-space: nowrap;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #topbar td:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    #topbar td.selected {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFF;
    }
    #topbar td.empty {
        cursor: auto;
    }
    #topbar td.empty:hover {
        background-color: #2d2d2d;
    }
    #topbar td span {
        display: image;
    }
```

OLD CODE
In the header

```
#topbar {
    width: 100%;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#topbar td {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#topbar td {
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#topbar td:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
#topbar td.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFF;
}
#topbar td.empty {
    cursor: auto;
}
#topbar td.empty:hover {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
#topbar td span {
    display: image;
}
```

In the body:

```
<table id="topbar">
    <tr>
        <td class="box2d" style="background: url(http://osxcrash.webs.com/MacBarMain.PNG) no-repeat">
        <td class="box2d" style="background: url(http://osxcrash.webs.com/MacBar.PNG) no-repeat">
        <td class="box2d" style="background: url(http://osxcrash.webs.com/MacBar2.png) no-repeat">
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: make sure the filenames are lowercase and also the link

Comment: What you show is not valid HTML - you are not closing the table cells

Comment: `display: image;` is not CSS. @Pekka the closing tag for `td` is optional in HTML.

Comment: My file names are OK even though one of them has an uppercase file name. Display: image; doesn't do anything so I just kept it there. Finally, Pekka, how do I close the cells correctly? Because all the cells end in the same way and only the first one shows up.

Comment: @PrplNinja no, tosho is right, closing is optional

Comment: It works for me when I enter something into each table cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are all displaying there are just all on top of each other so you can only see the first one.

Not sure how you want them to display but adding `display:block;` to `#topbar td` rule will stop them being on top of each other

**EDIT**: If you wish to show them on the same line you will need to specify a width value for each of the TD elements. The 100% value currently set is taking up the full screen so obscuring the view of the other TD elements

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mZEWN/

Comment: Yep `width: 100%` is source of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close your TD balise :

```
<table id="topbar">
    <tr>
        <td class="box2d" style="background: url(http://osxcrash.webs.com/MacBarMain.PNG) no-repeat"/>
        <td class="box2d" style="background: url(http://osxcrash.webs.com/MacBar.PNG) no-repeat"/>
        <td class="box2d" style="background: url(http://osxcrash.webs.com/MacBar2.png) no-repeat" />
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<td>` tags can't be self-closed like that